# Css overflow:hidden makes part of children components invisible even after returning them to visible area

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a message box banner on top of my screen with the following styles (I'm using React + Material UI):

```
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    textAlign: "left",
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: "100%",
  }}
```

The children components have the following animation:

```
  "scroll-text": {
    width: "80%",
    animation: `$marquee ${value}s linear infinite`,
    animationPlayState: "running",
    "&:hover": {
      animationPlayState: "paused",
    },
    "&focus-within": {
      animationPlayState: "paused",
    },
  },

 "@keyframes marquee": {
    "0%": { transform: "translateX(0);" },
    "100%": { transform: "translateX(-100%);" },
  },
```

The animation works fine, but the after the system has enough children components to surpass the width of the container, the new children components appear partially cut or even don't appear (check in the attached image that after the second empty circle there is the beginning of the component but the rest doestn't appear
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
"scroll-text": {
  width: "80%",
  animation: `$marquee ${value}s linear infinite`,
  animationPlayState: "running",
  "&:hover": {
    animationPlayState: "paused",
  },
  "&focus-within": {
    animationPlayState: "paused",
  },
  whiteSpace: "nowrap", // add this property
},
```

Comment: Unfortunalelly it didn't solve (makes the text appear more but the last message boxes are still being cut)